# Create a Django project in pydev from a mercurial repo

Tags: django, eclipse, mercurial, pydev

I like using the python editor pydev in Eclipse.  I want to team up with some people who've a python project (actually a Django site) stored in a mercurial repo. Can one create a new Django project in pydev that grabs code from a Mercurial repo? If so, how?

Thanks
Arthur

Answer (score 1):

Doing a google search on `does eclipse support mercurial` gives you:

1. [MercurialEclipse](http://javaforge.com/project/HGE) - an Eclipse plugin for Mercurial support, and I would suggest to start from here. This should work regardless of what sort of project you're working on.
2. A [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267982/which-has-better-eclipse-support-git-or-mercurial) on whether it is better to use git or Mercurial with Eclipse, which can help you out.

Additionally, if you didn't want to install the MercurialEclipse plugin, you could use Mercurial independently of Eclipse, clone the repository and then start a project with those files. In this case I would just make sure that your project meta files are in Mercurial's ignore list so they wouldn't get pushed to the remote repository.

If there's anything you'd like me to elaborate on, please comment. Good luck.